# Pentaho Data Integration: convert a text in number (Rhino)

Tags: javascript, rhino, pdi

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration and I need to convert the string value content in a variable named "density" in a numeric value.

For example if density = "6.5" I need to transform it in "6,5".

I've tried this Javascript code

```
var density = "6.5";
var num_density = parseFloat(density.replace(",", "."));
```

But it doesn't work and the error is

```
org.mozilla.javascript.UniqueTag cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

I think that is related to PDI uses the Rhino engine but I don't know how to solve or find an alternative way.

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It work as normally my friend.
[image]